# Expand array linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel

i have an array

```
char* temp;
temp=kmalloc(3,GFP_KERNEL);
```

i need to expand this array each time i call this function
Note: Realloc can't be used in linux kernel i dont know if it exists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Roll your own realloc but be noted that realloc is a poorly designed function interface. Just allocate a new buffer with kmalloc and memcpy the old data into the new buffer; that's essentially all that realloc does if it cannot expand the buffer in place.

Comment: I wouldn't keep doing 3-byte kmallocs and memcpy.  Just use kmalloc in larger chunks like 1K, then you only need to do the realloc once in a while

Answer (score 4):

`<linux/slab.h>` does have `krealloc()` to go with `kmalloc()`.  This was added in 2007 / kernel 2.6.22.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you should use a fixed size ring buffer based upon a mmapped memory(or something of that sort) instead of expanding allocation every time.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to using something like Linux's Flexible Array implementation. See  http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/flexible-arrays.txt;h=df904aec99044f8056ac530b9e9dc6de8f26f73e;hb=HEAD